# VBA Powerpoint : what is the VBA equivalent to "hyperlink to a different Powerpoint Presentation?

Tags: vba, focus, powerpoint

I want to use several slideshows (in kiosk mode if possible), to be able to jump between them, without going back in edit mode... 
No problem to do it with shapes and "hyperlink to a different powerpoint presentation".
But i'd need to do it also in VBA macros, in some slides. 
For example, after a quiz is finished, jump to another slideshowwindow and a given slide, and give focus to that slideshowwindow :
What would be the code like ?
I'm unable to give focus to the new slideshowwindow...
I suppose it is the equivalent of what "hyperlink to a different PPT Presentation does, but i can't figure to do it.
Thank you very much in advance !

Alex

Comment: [How to record a macro in PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127125/3111149)

Answer (score 0):

This Code opens a Presentation goes to Slide Number 5 and starts in Kiosk Mode

```
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPPT As PowerPoint.Presentation

'Open the Slideshow
Set myPPT = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(FileName:="filename.pptx")

Application.ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.ShowType = ppShowTypeKiosk

'You need this to work
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit
ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run

'Goto Slide number 5
myPPT.Windows(1).View.GotoSlide 5

'Start Slide Show
myPPT.SlideShowSettings.Run
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! If i want to open a second file, always in kiosk mode, and i want to focus on either this file or the other, do i need to call SlideShowWindow(i).activate ? What would be the code, to open a second file, and go to a slide, then have this slide displayed on front of screen ?