# I need help deciphering VBA instruction given in a previous post for "recording" macros in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to make sense of the instructions Bruno Leite provided back in 2011 to "record" macros in PowerPoint.  I rarely use VBA and am not sure how to implement his solution. Can someone give me more explicit instructions on how I can record macros in PPT?  Below is the text from his post . . .
[VBA PowerPoint Online Guide and How to Record a Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127006/vba-powerpoint-online-guide-and-how-to-record-a-macro)

---

To view the struct of objects use Watch (Shift +F9) in object.

For Example

```
dim ppt as powerpoint.Presentation

set ppt =activepresentation
```

add watch to ppt to view the struct of object Presentation

otherwise

Add a new class module

in the class declare

```
Private WithEvents ppt As PowerPoint.Application
```

in comon module declare one instance from classCreate(default is Class1) using

```
set x= new class1
```

Now in module class you can get events for you presentation (in left combo up the code window)

Bruno Leite
Sep 1, 2011

Comment: He is saying that you cannot use the Macro Recorder in PowerPoint and is advising that you use the Watch Window to view objects during run-time. This is a quick way to find an object's members, and find values that you're looking for. I suggest going to the official documentation for the object on learn.microsoft.com, where you can find a more complete list of all the methods, functions, and properties of that object.

Comment: The second part of the answer is briefly entertaining the idea that you can create a custom PowerPoint Application class, and expose the events to outside handlers. After having done so, you could assemble a team of developers and spend a few years of effort to create your own macro recorder.

Comment: If you can find a copy of Office 2003, it contains the last version of PowerPoint with a macro recorder. It can still be a time-saver to use, even though the object model has changed a lot in the last 20 years.